# connect to teamcity from java and download a build

Tags: java, teamcity

I've been googling how to connect to a TeamCity server and download a specific .war file. No luck.

I'm writing an application that needs to connect to TeamCity, download a war file, upload it to a server and some other stuff.

I can't figure out the TeamCity thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with artifacts in TeamCity. For example you add the following artifact path to your configuration: `src\YourProject\bin\Release\* => YourBuild.zip`

This will pack all files located in this folder in the zip file. See this blog [post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/02/26/artifact-packaging-with-teamcity/) for more examples.

The zip file itself is then available for download e.g. `http://localhost:8080/repository/download/bt6/180:id/YourBuild.zip`

To get the proper IDs (here `bt6` and `180`) for your download link you can use TeamCity's [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts) how to download build artifacts from TeamCity server.
Commons [HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) is known to work well. You need to authorize or to enable public access to your artifacts (see [more on this](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP)).

Hope this helps,
KIR